# How to get tag information from files on assets or raw folder

Tags: android

Im new with android and JAVA but im trying a simple app. Its a player that has its own mp3 files. So I put them all in the assets folder. I can play them without any problem. What I cant do is to read the meta-data, or tag information of the file such as Title, album, etc...
  Is it possible to get tag information from files on assets or raw folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are just raw files in your .apk.  You will need to use some code that parses the tag data out of an .mp3, and point it at that data in your .apk.